# With React, how to access the render return value of a child component

Tags: reactjs

I have a React Component that replaces some content inside a string or array of strings, and I have another Component that does something similar. Both return, in their `render()` methods, an array of strings. Now I would like to combine them, and use the output of the second component as the input of the first one.

Here's a very simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```js
class Container extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return ['Hello', 'World'];
    }
}

class Enhancer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        // Get actual content of the children,
        // not the React element.
        // How do I do that?
        const content = this.props.children;

        return content.splice(1, 0, 'Dear');
    }
}

render(
    <Enhancer>
        <Container />
    </Enhancer>
)

// Expected: HelloDearWorld
```

I have searched the Web and React's documentation, but I cannot find a way to do that. Is it possible to access the actual value of a child element in React?

Thanks!

***Edit: Solution!***

```js
function withSpecialContent(WrappedComponent, content) {
    return class extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent>
                { content }
            </WrappedComponent>;
        }
    }
}

class Enhancer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return content.splice(1, 0, 'Dear');
    }
}

render(
    withSpecialContent(Enhancer, ['Hello', 'World']);
)

// Result: HelloDearWorld
```

Comment: `Container` and `Enhancer` Component must be have a Parent/Children relationship? Or can they be siblings? In the latter case, would be ok for you to keep the array of strings in the state of the parent Component?

Comment: Yes, in my case Container and Enhancer both take a string as input, and produce something else. I need to result of Container to be passed to Enhancer, and only show the result of Enhancer's render function.

Comment: Uhm.. I've added an answer, let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you need is HOC:

https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: Thanks. To be a bit more specific, I had to add a HOC that did the same thing as one of my 2 components, and use that in the places where I wanted to combine the 2. I'm not entirely satisfied about this, but I guess that's the best way to do this kind of things with React. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you jsut need `Container` to be "in the middle" between the input and `Enhancer` Component. Something like the following:

```js
class Enhancer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            this.props.arrStr.map((str, index) => {
                /* Here you have the computation made from `Enhancer`. */
                return <p key={index}>Dear {str}</p>;
            })
        );
    }    
}

class Container extends React.Component {
    render() {
        /* Perform operations on the strings. */
        const processedStrings = this.props.arrStr.map(str => str + ", how are you?");
        
        /* You pass the processed strings to the enhancer. */
        return <Enhancer arrStr={processedStrings} />;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Container arrStr={["Foo", "Bar", "Miz"]} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, sadly that wouldn't work for me, I cannot have my components depend on one another, they have to be independent. It however turns out I've been able to solve my problem with a HOC as jsdeveloper suggested.